# How do you create a User instance in another factory in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, factories

I am trying to create some test data using factories in Laravel 5.5. I am running this

```
factory('App\Thread', 3)->create();
```

I get the error message **Column 'user_id' cannot be null**

```
Column 'user_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into thread
s` (user_id, title, body, updated_at, created_at) values (, Quia modi
aperiam eos aut., Sed voluptate ut quia ut. Et accusamus eaque est amet. Veniam
consectetur exercitationem id facere., 2017-09-04 04:38:11, 2017-09-04 04:38:11)
)'
```

My Thread factory creates a new instance user, but it doesn't seem to return a value.

```
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Thread::class, function (Faker $faker) {

return [
    'user_id' => function () {
                return factory('App\User')->make()->id;
    },
    'title' => $faker->sentence,
    'body' => $faker->paragraph,
];
});
```

I haven't modified the user factory at all. I have copied and pasted from the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database-testing#relationships) and cannot get it. Any help would be appreciated I'm new to this and I'm sure it's something simple.

Comment: You should use ->create() instead of ->make() in the thread factory

Comment: What is the difference? I see three users added to the database either way. I thought make wouldn't save them.

Answer (score 0):

I was typing

```
factory(App\Thread::class, 3)->create();
```

instead of

```
factory('App\Thread', 3)->create();
```

I did not know they were different.